# Inner Join subquery in Postgresql results in error

Tags: postgresql, count, subquery, sql-order-by, inner-join

There is my request to find actualities on my website, I got error in this request and I don't know what i need to do for solve this error

Error:

> Column "quote_plus_normal_gr_publi.id_post_normal" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate fun

Query:

```
SELECT 
    publi.date, publi.mess, publi, publi.profil, publi.color, 
    publi.name, publi.search
FROM 
    publi
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         id_post_normal, COUNT(id_post_normal)
     FROM 
         quote_plus_normal_gr_publi
     ORDER BY 
         id_post_normal) q ON q.id_post_normal = publi.id_post_normal
WHERE 
    publi.id_personnes = 1
ORDER BY 
    date DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something wrong in your select statement

```
SELECT publi.date, publi.mess, publi, publi.profil, publi.color, publi.name, publi.search

FROM publi
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id_post_normal, COUNT(id_post_normal)
    FROM quote_plus_normal_gr_publi
    ORDER BY id_post_normal
) q 
ON q.id_post_normal = publi.id_post_normal
WHERE publi.id_personnes = 1
ORDER BY date DESC
```

in first select there are just publi and don't have column to call

```
select publi.date, publi.mess, publi, publi.profil
```

so i try query and make similar to you and i don't have any error to show.

first why the error show up group by? do you try another query? not this query?

Comment: It's that tank you